# Schema.org: Having a Product as "about" property

Tags: html, seo, microdata, rich-snippets

I want to define a Product as the main content of a webpage using Schema.org markup. My idea with the following HTML is to use the structure:

```
 - Webpage
 -- WebPageElement (mainContentOfPage of Webpage)
 --- Product (about of WebPageElement which is mainContentOfPage of Webpage)
```

However, using this markup, Google does not seem to recognize the Product properties such as the aggregateRating. The "structured markup tool" is only satisfied if I remove the "about" property on Product. But then the structure breaks into:

```
- Webpage
-- WebPageElement (mainContentOfPage of Webpage)
-- Product
```

Product is no longer a part of WebPageElement. Even if I use the property "mainContentOfPage" directly on the Product node, I get the same result: The Product is not recognized properly. It seems like the Product node cannot have any itemprops. **So how should I proceed?**

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPageElement" itemprop="mainContentOfPage">
        <div itemprop="about" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
            <h1 itemprop="name">Acme Toaster Oven</h1>
            <div itemprop="description">It toasts AND bakes.</div>
            <div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">Rated <span itemprop="ratingValue">3</span>/5 based on <span itemprop="reviewCount">2</span> reviews</div>
            <div itemprop="review" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review"><span itemprop="name">A great toaster</span> - by <span itemprop="author">John</span>,
                <meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2013-10-16">October 26, 2013
                <div itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating"><span itemprop="ratingValue">5</span>/5</div>
                <span itemprop="reviewBody">First I had bread.  Then I had toast.  Magic!</span>
            </div>
            <div itemprop="review" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review"><span itemprop="name">A small oven</span> - by <span itemprop="author">Mary</span>,
                <meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2013-10-16">October 26, 2013
                <div itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating"><span itemprop="ratingValue">1</span>/5</div>
                <span itemprop="reviewBody">My 18-pound turkey wouldn't fit in this thing.</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The HTML can be tested here: http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets

### Update

After experimenting with "itemref", I got pretty good results with this code in [Google's tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) and [Yandex](http://webmaster.yandex.com/microtest.xml) and the [Structured Data Linter](http://linter.structured-data.org/).

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPageElement" itemprop="mainContentOfPage">
        <meta itemprop="about" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" itemref="theProduct" />
    </div>
    <div id="theProduct">
        <h1 itemprop="name">Acme Toaster Oven</h1>
        <div itemprop="description">It toasts AND bakes.</div>
        <div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">Rated <span itemprop="ratingValue">3</span>/5 based on <span itemprop="reviewCount">2</span> reviews</div>
        <div itemprop="review" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review"><span itemprop="name">A great toaster</span> - by <span itemprop="author">John</span>,
            <meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2013-10-16">October 26, 2013
            <div itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating"><span itemprop="ratingValue">5</span>/5</div>
            <span itemprop="reviewBody">First I had bread.  Then I had toast.  Magic!</span>
        </div>
        <div itemprop="review" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review"><span itemprop="name">A small oven</span> - by <span itemprop="author">Mary</span>,
            <meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2013-10-16">October 26, 2013
            <div itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating"><span itemprop="ratingValue">1</span>/5</div>
            <span itemprop="reviewBody">My 18-pound turkey wouldn't fit in this thing.</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The only side effect is that the reviews and aggregateRating seem to connect to both the WebPage and the Product. I don't know if that's bad.

Comment: Not sure I follow your HTML structure, but in the third line of your code `about` is not property that's nested under [Product](http://schema.org/Product), so you will get errors with the Structured Data Testing Tool and Google likely isn't going to display it until you fix that.

Comment: As far as I understand, all itemprops are properties of the parent node. So the "about" property belongs to WebPageElement in this case. And the about property is supposed to be a Thing, which Product is a subclass of.

Comment: Does that work then? ;-) The schema.org table for [Product](http://schema.org/Product) lists the `Properties from Thing` and the `Properties from Product` that can be used - `about` is not one of those. Just trying to help you fix the error you're seeing.

Comment: Sure, but please look at it this way: WebPageElement has a property called "about". It is supposed to be "The subject matter of the content" and of type Thing. The Product is a Thing. So in my case, the Product is a property of WebPageElement. Is that logic wrong?

Comment: See my update. I think I got it working...?

Comment: I ran your first example through [developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/) and it seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 4):

Last week’s Schema.org release ([version 2.0](http://schema.org/docs/releases.html#v2.0)) introduced two relevant properties:

- [`mainEntity`](http://schema.org/mainEntity)
- [`mainEntityOfPage`](http://schema.org/mainEntityOfPage)

This allows you to omit `WebPageElement` (which is not very useful in the first place) and use something like this:

```html
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">

  <!-- properties about the web page -->

  <div itemprop="mainEntity" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <!-- properties about the product, which is the primary entity -->
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon an article saying one may need to declare *itemprop* in the html element, like this:

```
<html lang="sv" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" itemprop="[canonical]">
```

where [canonical] is to be replaced with the actual canonical link of the page.

I am not sure if this will solve the problem. If not, there is a schema creator that may be helpful at http://schema-creator.org/product.php

Comment: Sorry, this did not have any effect on the result. Also the Product needs to be a part of the page, not the page itself. Using WebPage instead of Product in your example did not help either.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with googlify's answer. Also, rather than having to use schema.org/Product. You might consider using [schema.org/Offer](http://schema.org/Offer) instead and then with the itemprop=offers to help you nest it inside like you want it. Although, take my advice and stop using the [schema.org/WebPageElement](http://schema.org/WebPageElement) itemtype tag all together. It;s over redundant and nit that useful. you can get away with just using the `itemprop="mainContentOfPage"` by itself and it will work fine. Just be sure to add the `sameAs`, `url` and `about` properties if you are going to use `mainEntity` or `mainEntityOfPage`.