# New required mainEntityOfPage for article structured data

Tags: seo, microdata, schema.org, structured-data, google-rich-snippets-tool

I had a look at the article structured data as proposed by Google and saw that there are a new required and recommended fields, they weren't there last week. Here is the link:

https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/articles

The first property on the list is :

- mainEntityOfPage.@id (recommended)

I don't understand what the value of the property must be? What is this property? Is it a link to:

- http://schema.org/Article

..or a link to the current blog post like:

- http://www.example.com/blog/1001/my-blog-article

They have this in their sample code:

```
<meta itemscope itemprop="mainEntityOfPage"  itemType="https://schema.org/WebPage" itemid="https://google.com/article" />
```

This what I currently have, it does not yet conform to the test tool's rules - I am still busy adding all the required properties and at the same time trying to add the recommended properties there as well:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
   <h1 itemprop="headline">
      <a href="http:///www.example.com/blog/1001/my-blog-article" itemprop="url">My Blog Article</a>
   </h1>
   <p>Written by
      <span itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
         <span itemprop="name">Mase Kind</span>
      </span> on
      <time itemprop="datePublished" datetime="2015-11-16T15:30:00+02:00">November 16, 2015</time>
      <meta itemprop="dateModified" content="2015-12-10T12:29:00+02:00" />
      <div itemprop="publisher" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
         <div itemprop="logo" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject"></div>
         <meta itemprop="name" content="My Company Name" />
      </div>
   </p>
   <div itemprop="articleBody">
      <p>first article body</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

I also have this in my document:

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
...
</body>
```

Will this in any way conflict with the code sample supplied by Google?

Comment: Just saw the same thing happen to my site this morning and landed on this thread.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [`mainEntityOfPage` property](http://schema.org/mainEntityOfPage) is used to give the URL of a page on which the *thing* is the main entity. It might become clearer if you look at the inverse property [`mainEntity`](http://schema.org/mainEntity): this gives the main entity for a page ([see an example](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/81406/17633)).

For example, for a web page that contains a single blog post, you could provide one of these:

- `BlogPosting` → `mainEntityOfPage` → `WebPage`
- `WebPage` → `mainEntity` → `BlogPosting`

These properties are useful to convey what the main content on a page is (because pages might contain multiple items, e.g., an `ItemList` with related `WebPage` items, a `Person` describing the author, a `WebSite` giving some metadata, etc.).

(See [my answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34467088/1591669) for a more detailed explanation.)

---

There are [two ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34245547/1591669) how to use `mainEntityOfPage`:

- provide the URL of the page
- embed/reference the page item (typically a `WebPage`)

The second one often doesn’t make much sense (you would rather use the inverse property `mainEntity`), and probably for that reason Google recommends/expects the first one.

For providing the URL, you could simply use a `link` element:

```html
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
  <link itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" href="http://example.com/article-1" />
</article>
```

Google’s Structured Data Testing Tool accepts this.

In the [Articles Rich Snippet example](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/articles#examples), Google is using a `meta` element with `itemid` instead:

> ```html
> <meta itemscope itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" itemType="https://schema.org/WebPage" itemid="https://google.com/article"/>
> ```

This is invalid HTML5+Microdata: If the `meta` element has an `itemprop` attribute, it [must also have a `content` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22415563/1591669).

Comment: what if we also provide content with url in meta, e.g. `<meta itemscope itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" itemType="https://schema.org/WebPage" itemid="https://google.com/article" content='https://google.com/article' />`

It'll validate fine and not showing error in structured data testing tool

Comment: @StarWars: Yes, that’s the way to make this `meta` element valid. Note that the `content` value would be ignored, so you could provide an empty value.

Comment: okay, I've now added content="" to meta tag.

Comment: Why google uses `meta` instead of `link` in its examples? both of these validate in the structured data testing tool. Although, the preview is different. When `link` is used, it has `mainEntityOfPage http://example.com/article-1` while in the case of `meta` it shows `@id` and `@type` attributes.

Comment: @StarWars: Yes, that’s exactly the difference: the `meta` way creates a new item with a type and a URI as identifier, the `link` way just links to a page. I have no idea why Google’s documentation uses `meta`, especially since I think the `link` way is more simple.

Answer (score 2):

> What is this property?

It's supplementary to the `url` and `sameAs` properties, as described in the [`mainEntity` background](https://schema.org/docs/datamodel.html#mainEntityBackground).

It has an idiosyncratic name as it may be applied to all items of type `Thing`. If it applied only to `Articles` it could have been called `mainTopic`/`mainTopicOfArticle` and been more clear.

> I don't understand what the value of the property must be?

The value of the property is expected to be a item of type `CreativeWork` or a `URL` referencing that work [according to](https://schema.org/mainEntityOfPage) Schema.org. That means it could also be an `Article` or `BlogPosting` as you mentioned. However, if you're building out AMP pages, the value should be a URL.

> Will this in any way conflict with the code sample supplied by Google?

Despite what Google's Structured Data Testing Tool says [their documentation](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/articles) no longer recommends using the `mainEntityOfPage` for non-AMP pages so you're free to omit it.