# Schema.org BlogPosting mainEntityOfPage vs. WebPage mainEntity

Tags: google-search, schema.org, rich-snippets, articles, json-ld

I am still having difficulty in trying to understand what the `mainEntityOfPage.@id` is and why it is recommended by Google. I am referring specifically to articles, blog posts and similar schemas. Here is the article that I read:

https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/articles

I currently have my blog post page setup like this (I have left out most of the required fields otherwise this post gets too long):

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
     "@@context": "http://schema.org",
     "@@type": "WebPage",
     "breadcrumb": {
          "@@type": "BreadcrumbList",
          "itemListElement": [{
               "@@type": "ListItem",
               "item": {
                    "@@id": "http://www.example.com",
                    "name": "My Website"
               },
               "position": 1
          }, {
               "@@type": "ListItem",
               "item": {
                    "@@id": "http://www,example.com/blog",
                    "name": "Blog"
               },
               "position": 2
          }, {
               "@@type": "ListItem",
               "item": {
                    "@@id": "http://www.example.com/blog/1001/test-blog-post",
                    "name": "Test Blog Post"
               },
               "position": 3
          }]
     },
     "mainEntity": {
          "@@type": "BlogPosting",
          "headline": "Test Blog Post",
          "url": "http://www.example.com/blog/1001/test-blog-post"
     }
}
</script>
```

Using `mainEntity` the way I did, is this the same thing as using `mainEntityOfPage.@id`? If it is not, how do I change my code to fit in with Google's requirements?

Comment: (Your) related question: [New required mainEntityOfPage for article structured data](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/87940/17633)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@unor posted detailed answers here:

- [New required mainEntityOfPage for article structured data](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/87940/new-required-mainentityofpage-for-article-structured-data)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34466028/how-to-implement-mainentityofpage-to-this-specific-site/34467088#34467088

It would be much easier to understand if Google's structured data testing tool would remove the warning if you don't specify `mainEntityOfPage.@id` but specify `mainEntity`. This is how I currently have it.

Comment: The second link is clear and comprehensive without saying too much. A++